# how to avoid a particular task in gradle when building through command line

Tags: android, gradle

I wanted to build an android project by running gradle build but I am getting  this error

```
 Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources' 

  com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
 org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
 '/Users/abc/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt'' finished
 with non-zero exit value 1
```

how can i avoid gradle to run this particular task ??

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to use the `-x` or `--exclude-task` options. You can read about it in the official docs [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:excluding_tasks_from_the_command_line).

You just nee to run you build as follows:

```
gradle build --exclude-task processDebugResources
```

Although this could be an option, I'm not sure, whether it's a good solution, because just skipping some task doesn't solve a root problem, which caused your build failure.

You can try to solve the problem by cleaning and rebuilding the project. If this won't help, you can also try to update Android SDK build tool in your SDK manager and updating `buildToolsVersion` in your `build.gradle` script.

Comment: I have tried by `--exclude-task` and it is giving me  another task `compileDebugJavaWithJavac` failure error.First when i typed `gradle build --continue ` command it showed only processDebugResources and lint task failure but it is showing another new task failure and when i exclude that one it is showing another task failure how to get rid of this??

Comment: @cks as I've mentioned above - you have to try to solve the root problem, since skipping a task is not always a solution. You can find a number of questions all over SO related to the same issue you have